# Problem Reaching $\frac{\pi^6}{960}$ with Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

I do not know where I am making a mistake... The problem says that obtaining the Fourier series for the $2\pi$ periodic odd function $f(x)=x(\pi-x)$ on $[0,\pi]$ and using Parseval's relation I should obtain $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{960}.$$

So, I already know that the odd extension for the function is
$$f(x)=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}\sin(2n-1)x$$
where
$$b_n=\frac{8}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}\Longrightarrow b_n^2=\frac{64}{\pi^2}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}.$$
On the other hand
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi [x(\pi-x)]^2 dx=\frac{16 \pi^4}{15}.$$
Putting this together with Parseval's
$$\frac{64}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}=\frac{16 \pi^4}{15}$$
which results in
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{60}$$
and not what the problem states... ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The integral is wrong. Don't forget $f$ is odd. So for negative $x$, $f(x)\ne x(\pi-x)$. You have to compute twice the integral on $[0,\pi]$ instead.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That little detail changes everything...thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct fourier series. But as Jean-Claude Arbaut says you're doing the integral in Parseval Formula wrong. For the sine series use instead:

$$ \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi |f(x)|^2 dx = \sum_{n>1} |b_n|^2 $$

This gives the desired result:

$$ \sum_{n>1} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^6} = \frac{\pi^6}{960}$$

However I don't know how to get from here to:

$$ ζ (6) =  \sum_{n>1} \frac{1}{n^6} = \frac{\pi^6}{945}$$

Maybe I have to compute the cosine fourier series for the even terms?

Comment: $\zeta(6) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^6} = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{(2n)^6}+\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^6} = \frac{1}{64}\zeta(6) +  \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}$ so solving for $\zeta(6)$ gives $\zeta(6) =  \frac{64}{63} \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}$ . Not sure if that's in the spirit of the question, though.

Comment: Yes, thank you vert much.